# Gaussian White Noise to Hodgkin Huxley Equations

Tags: python

Adding Gaussian White noise to the classical Hodgkin Huxley ODE for the membrane potential

Hi guys,

I have found this code for the membrane potential evaluated via the Hodgkin Huxley equation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from scipy.integrate import odeint

#runtime in milliseconds

#print("Type in the runtime-interval (in milliseconds)")

#t_0 = input()
#t_1 = input()

t_0 = 0.0
t_1 = 200.0
print("The interval of runtime is:")
print(t_0, t_1)

#Potassium (alpha_n, beta_n) and Sodium (alpha_m, beta_m, alpha_h, beta_h) ion-channel rate functions


def alpha_n(V):
    return (0.01*(10.0-V))/(np.exp((10.0-V)/10.0)-1.0)

def alpha_m(V):
    return (0.1*(25.0-V))/(np.exp((25.0-V)/10.0)-1)

def beta_n(V):
    return 0.125*np.exp(-V/80.0)

def beta_m(V):
    return 4.0*np.exp(-V/18.0)

def alpha_h(V):
    return 0.07*np.exp(-V/20.0)

def beta_h(V):
    return (1.0)/((np.exp((30.0-V)/10.0))+1)

#mostly used parameters

#Sodium potential (mV)
V_NA = 50.0

#Potassium Potential
V_K = -77.0

#Leak Potential
V_L = -54.4

#Potassium channel conductance
g_k = 36.0

#Sodium channel conductance
g_NA = 120.0

#Leak channel conductance
g_L = 0.3

#Membrane capacitance
C = 1.0

#equally ('distributed') time values

T = np.linspace(t_0,t_1,10000)

#please input the stimulus (first of all with a fixed stimulus)
#one spike below
def stim(t):
    if 0.0 < t < 1.0:
        return 150.0
    elif 35.0 < t < 36.0 :
        return 5000.0
    return 0.0



#steady - state values

def n_infty(V = 0.0):
    return alpha_n(V)/(alpha_n(V)+beta_n(V))

def m_infty(V = 0.0):
    return alpha_m(V)/(alpha_m(V)+beta_m(V))

def h_infty(V = 0.0):
    return alpha_h(V)/(alpha_h(V)+beta_h(V))

def tau_m(V = 0.0):
    return 1.0/(alpha_m(V)+beta_m(V))

def tau_n(V = 0.0):
    return 1.0/(alpha_n(V)+beta_n(V))

def tau_h(V = 0.0):
    return 1.0/(alpha_h(V)+beta_h(V))

#derivatives


def derivatives(x, z):

    dx = np.zeros((4,))

    V = x[0]
    m = x[1]
    n = x[2]
    h = x[3]

    dx[0] = (stim(z)-g_NA*np.power(m,3.0)*h*(V-V_NA)-g_k*np.power(n,4.0)*(V-V_K)-g_L*(V-V_L))/1.0

    dx[1] = (m_infty(V)-m)/tau_m(V)

    dx[2] = (n_infty(V)-n)/tau_n(V)

    dx[3] = (h_infty(V)-h)/tau_h(V)

    return dx

X = np.array([0.0,m_infty(),n_infty(),h_infty()])

V_x = odeint(derivatives,X,T)

print(V_x)





plt.plot(T,V_x)
plt.xlabel('Time in ms')
plt.ylabel('Membrane Potential in mV')
```

I would like to add a gaussian white noise process - but I am not quite sure how, because I am not a great python user -

maybe

```
noise = numpy.random.normal(mean=0.0, std=1.0, size=T)
```

and

```
 dx[0] =
 (stim(z)-g_NA*np.power(m,3.0)*h*(V-V_NA)-g_k*np.power(n,4.0)*(V-V_K)-g_L*(V-V_L))/1.0
 + noise
```

Can I simply add this to the differential equation?

Kind regards and many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to add the noise argument to the function,

```
def derivatives(x, z,noisyInput):
```

which you already creat your noise with normal distribution.

```
noisyInput = np.ones(length)*7 + np.random.normal(0,3,length)
```

you simply add the noise term in the dvdt term devided by the capacity.

```
dx[0] = (noisyInput + stim(z)-g_NA*np.power(m,3.0)*h*(V-V_NA)-g_k*np.power(n,4.0)*(V-V_K)-g_L*(V-V_L))/1.0
```

and you should pass the noise to the function.

```
V_x = odeint(derivatives,X,T,args=(noisyInput,))
```

you can also check the code I wrote :
https://github.com/nosratullah/HodgkinHuxely

Comment: Hi and many thanks. The goal would be to see if the ums amplitude of the noise grows proportional to the square root of sodium channels - do see a way to get this result?

Comment: Can you be more specific what do you mean by square root of sodioum channels? Do you mean the number of sodium channels or something else? by the way if you're gonna play with noise and other parameters I recommend using some numerical calculation instead of using odeint function. you can also check the code I wrote in github. https://github.com/nosratullah/HodgkinHuxely
be in tough!

Comment: Hi, i mean that the noise should grow proportional to the square root of number of sodium channels - i will write you directly on github. kind regards